# Compile Intel TBB for Android - ARMv7 ARMv8 MIPS

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, tbb

I've found some serious difficulties in getting a working .so library to develop an Android app with Android NDK and intel TBB.
Basically I've downoaded version 4.4 Update 4 bundle for Android and followed the steps there (kind of, since the docs are not correct...).

Problem is that I can only get x86 and x86_64 .so libraries when compiling, since there are no armeabi-XXX or mips folders with the necessary .so in there.

Using the suggested command `./ndk-build.cmd tbb target=android arch=arm` does not produce anything, in fact it tells me

> /workspace/tbb44_20160413oss/lib/android/mips/libtbb.so library not found. Copy mips version of library to /home/filippo/workspace/tbb44_20160413oss/lib/android/mips folder to enable its build.

and the same for the other missing directories.

Threfore using only `./ndk-build.cmd tbb target=android` gives me a cuople of dirs: x86 and x86_64 which I can use in Android Studio, and work with the emulator.

The result is taht I can properly test my apps on an emulator but cannot make it work into my personal device.
What am I missing here?

**Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI := x86 x86_64 // if I choose all, of course it won't find the .so for the other architectures
APP_GNUSTL_FORCE_CPP_FEATURES := exceptions rtti
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#
# TBB
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtbb
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtbb.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


#
# Main module
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := myndkapp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libtbb
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in 'jni/Application.mk' you can use targets 'ia32', 'intel64', 'arm' and 'arm64'.

Also it looks like you trying to build on Windows platform, so you should add a `tbb_os=windows` to your make command like this:

`C:\TEMP\tbb44_20160413oss\src>ndk-build.cmd tbb tbbmalloc target=android arch=arm tbb_os=windows`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've looked in more detail, and I do not have the /src directory inside the root of the project i.e. /tbb44_20160413oss/src does not exist, neither does a /jni folder with the Application.mk file in it.
I am running on Linux Mint x64 currently!

Comment: The two files I copied there are the files of my project, in which I've copied the .so I found in /tbb44_20160413oss/lib/android in my project dir, but as I stated up there, there aren't folders for all architectures...

Comment: Could you please download _Source_ package from https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download 
It looks like you have a binary package.

Comment: Oh I thought that downloading the Android bundle was enough to get it working on Android ;) but since I'm not experienced in using makefiles now I don't know how my Android.mk should look like. Can you give an example of that? Thanks!

Comment: You should use tbb makefiles only once to get tbb libraries(command above). Example of applications project for Android studio and Eclipce projects you can find in examples\parallel_for\tachyon\ folder

Comment: Yeah I saw that on another forum, trying to compile that particular example gives errors though. It's missing the correct paths in the Android.mk file therefore it can't find the libs...
My problem is now that I have compiled the libs, how can I include them in my project?

Comment: You should source tbbvars.sh from 'build/$os_$arch_$compiler_$target_*' directory